# My code only works with letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Im trying to get a input user and set it, that way I can run my following code (PRINT PDFs) but this only work withs letter and numbers like "A2, A3, A1000, etc" The problem is that I have just number "1, 2, 3,4..." in my database.

This is my code:

```
function promptUserToSelectInvoices(data) {
  // Prompts the user to enter invoice numbers separated by commas
  var selectedInvoices = [];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Select Invoices to Print', 'Enter the invoice numbers separated by commas:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  if (response.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var input = response.getResponseText().trim();
    Logger.log(input)
    selectedInvoices = input.split(',').map(function(value) {
      return value.trim();
    });

    // Calls the PrintSelectedToPDF() function with the selectedInvoices array
    PrintSelectedToPDF(selectedInvoices);
  }
}

function PrintSelectedToPDF(invoicesToPrint) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var databaseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Database');
  var invoiceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Invoice');
  
  var dataRange = databaseSheet.getRange(3, 12, databaseSheet.getLastRow() -2, 1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var valueToPrint = data[i][0];
    Logger.log(valueToPrint);
    
    // Check if invoicesToPrint is empty or includes the current invoice number
    if (invoicesToPrint.length === 0 || invoicesToPrint.includes(valueToPrint)) {
      invoiceSheet.getRange('Q7').setValue(valueToPrint);
      
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet.getId() + '/export?';
      var params = {
        exportFormat: 'pdf',
        format: 'pdf',
        size: 'letter',
        portrait: 'true',
        fitw: 'true',
        sheetnames: 'false',
        printtitle: 'false',
        top_margin: 0,
        bottom_margin: 0,
        left_margin: 0,
        right_margin: 0,
        gid: invoiceSheet.getSheetId()
      };
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var range = ss.getRange("invoice!A1:V41");
      var rangeParam = '&range=' + range.getA1Notation();
      url += getUrlParams(params) + rangeParam;
      
      var backoffTime = 500;
      var maxBackoffTime = 5000;
      var attempts = 0;
      var response;
```

Comment: Braces in `PrintSelectedToPDF` are unbalanced.

Comment: Can you point them out? I don't get it

Comment: But I don't think thats the problem because how I said when I set invoice numbers like "A1" in my database the code runs well, the problem is when I try to use just numbers... I actually don't put the entire code here with final brackets and other things

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var valueToPrint = data[i][0];
```

to this:

```
var valueToPrint = data[i][0].toString();
```

Possibly, the values are considered numbers, and the splitted input is considered a string

Comment: I did it and not working :/